# Book suggestions! I am confused

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations

Well I am a graduate Physics student. I am going to have Electrodynamics in next semester. I am confused between choice of book to follow. I want something advanced than Griffith but less advanced than Jackson. I hit upon two choices. One is Classical electromagnetism by Jerrold Franklin and another one is Electromagnetism a problem solving approach by Markus Zahn. Please suggest which one I should use.

Comment: PS. I also thought of using lectures on Electromagnetism by Ashok Das but they are really good but I didn't find enough problems.

Comment: Note that [resource-recommendation questions, while allowed, are restricted on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed). Please read that link carefully, as well as the duplicated linked in the banner above the question. If the existing resources are insufficient, you should edit this question to explain in detail why they're not enough and what you are looking for beyond what those resources have to offer.

Comment: I wish you would have thought about answering the question before writing this useless comment considering the experience you have. This is something that sucks about this site.

Comment: I agree, these guys are obsessed with these lame rules.

Comment: @AdityaSharma why answer duplicates? There's already plenty of answers in the links above. The comment by Emilio is quite correct in that if the links are indeed insufficient, the question should be clarified.